# Silverstripe Userform and form problem submit buttons value disappears

Tags: silverstripe, userform

Silverstripe 3.7 php 7 Userform add on

See here on my dev site http://new.skilltec.co.uk/contact-us/

Form problem. Send form button text disappears when clicked but does send form when text disappears you can click what is left without send form text and it sends. This happens on Mac Chrome but not Safari or Firefox. PC happens on IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Cannot for the life of me find out what is wrong. Help has anyone had this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found a javascript focus function i'd put in the upgrade after hours of searching doh. At least I know it doesn't work on safari and firefox for mac :o)